# Trouble connecting to my database and inserting info via PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

This script works through a free webhosting service, but not the paid hosting service I have via iFastNet. I use cpanel to create databases and etc.

Here's my script for registering new users in my database. It is communicating with files in my android studio project.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_username", "my_password", "userdatabase_name");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $username, $email, $password);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["username"] = $email;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Not sure if any of you have experience with this. I'm assuming it's the web hosting service. Hopefully one of you have had this problem, and can provide a simple solution.

It's important to bring up that I can connect to the database via MYSQL Workbench, and I'm able to insert data into my table there. I just can't insert data via the simple user registration I created for an android application. It worked via a free web hosting service though.

-Also, before anyone mentions it, my user has all privileges for the database on the paid web hosting service.

Comment: Did  you get any  error  massages?

Comment: @SupunAbesekara I do not get any error messages when running the android application. Nor does the domain return any kind of error.

Comment: your `config.php` on local , and database on webhosting?

Comment: I'd temporarily turn on error reporting, it's probably turned off.

Comment: @jack everything should be through the webhost. I was just testing the connection remotely, but the provider states that the hostname should be 'localhost'.

Comment: @trollboy how would I turn that on? I'm new to this. I don't think I have access to their configuration files though.

Comment: @trollboy I turned it on, but the scripts only return that the fields are empty. No errors are returned on the android application, as if it's not even communicating with the website.

Comment: why not use `config.php` on webhosting , so if you want insert data , just include config with `include 'https://yourdomain.com/config.php';`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.

Comment: @FrankerZ do you know how I would generate an error when doing a POST request via my script? I run the application through android studio or my phone, but no errors are reported when I build the project or when I enter the information. I wrote another script with static values that a user doesn't need to enter through the application, and I ran the script directly from my domain and it inserted the values successfully. So I'm stumped. I asked the hosting service if they allow POST request, and they said that they do. I just can't pinpoint anything when the same code works elsewhere.

Comment: @jack where would I obtain config.php ? Everything is automated via Cpanel and their web hosting service, so I wasn't sure about any other necessary files. I do have an error reporting php file in my domain, just to put that out there, but it hasn't returned an error. I think that config file may do the trick, but is there a specific config file I need to obtain?